# Notices on validation script

Tags: php

I'm working on a validation script right now.

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['process'] == 1) {    
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    if (empty($first_name) && empty($last_name)){
      echo "Howdy, stranger";
    }else{
      echo "Hello there, ".$first_name." ".$last_name;
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Form validation example</title>
  <style>
    input{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Form Validation Example</h1>
  <h2>Please enter your name</h2>

  <form action="validation_example.php" method="post">
    <label for="first_name">First name:</label>
    <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" />

    <label for="last_name">Last name:</label>
    <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" />

    <input type="hidden" name="process" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I'm getting this :

```
Notice: Undefined index: process in on line 2
```

It's a fairly obvious error, but what should I throw in to stop this line of code running thus preventing the error?

Comment: Check that $_POST['process'] is set first with isset function.

Comment: How it's related to mysql and mysqli?

Comment: @orangepill should I get a mod to delete this then?

Comment: @GnikcufSullBhit I tried your script with everything inside one file, and it worked while using the following: `<form action="" method="post">` (as self)

Comment: @GnikcufSullBhit Try using `<form action="" method="post">` instead and then get back to me with your result(s).

Comment: @GnikcufSullBhit Actually, there is nothing wrong with your form. I just made up two seperate files and everything checks out. Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Fred No it's OK, everything works thanks. I just ported this script over to my real file and it's doing what it says on the tin.

Comment: @GnikcufSullBhit You're welcome, glad everything worked out, cheers. *"Peace"*

Comment: @GnikcufSullBhit The review process will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['process']) && $_POST['process'] == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

if(array_key_exists('process', $_POST) && $_POST['process'] == 1)

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` or `array_key_exists`  before you use the variable